# Magento 2 : Change store view when currency is changed

Tags: multistore, multicurrency, store-switcher, switcher, store-currency

Is it possible to change the store view when currency is changed?

For example, On my site, I have **3 currency** and **3 stores view**, Now when **I'm switching my currency USD** then **storeview** also needs to change to an **English store view**.

Can anyone help me to do that?

Any help would be appreciated thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You should use post dispatch event and check fullaction name

> event name :: controller_action_postdispatch

> action name :: directory_currency_switch

> PHP file

```
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer) {
        if ($this->_request->getFullActionName() == 'directory_currency_switch'){
            // your condition to change store view here
        }
    }
```